# Rails: Setting tag owner with acts-as-taggable-on and tag_list direct assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

Using https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on I need to set the ownership of the Tags I create using the tag_list direct assignment method described there.

Here is what I am doing now:

```
@blog.tag_list = "red, blue, green"
@blog.save
```

And I have the User set as a Tagger

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tagger
end
```

The README then describes how to setup tag ownership by various tag methods, but there is no discussion of how to set ownership direct via tag_list.

Is this possible?  Or do I need to avoid direct assignment to set ownership?

Answer (score 3):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6545342/86915

```
  # In a taggable model (Blog):
  before_save :set_tag_owner
  def set_tag_owner
    # Set the owner of some tags based on the current tag_list
    set_owner_tag_list_on(self.user, :tags, self.tag_list)
    # Clear the list so we don't get duplicate taggings
    self.tag_list = nil
  end

  # In the view:
  <%= f.text_field :tag_list, :value => @blog.all_tags_list %>
```

Comment: This was perfect! @kayatela, you should make this as accepted!