# Custom field in ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging (acts-as-taggable-on gem) how to save values for this custom field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tagging, acts-as-taggable-on

I have a custom id field in my tagging table, which makes reference to other model. Im having some trouble when saving the tags (the tags are saved correctly and so the taggings, but not for my custom field), i dont know where to save this custom field. I try making an observer like in this example [Update owner tags via form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619361/update-owner-tags-via-form) but its not working.

```
class TaggingObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging

  # Before save add :tagger_id using refs on the object witch 'taggable' and owner of this 'taggable'
  def before_save(tagging)
    puts "AAAAAAA"

  end
end
```

My file name for this observer is call tagging_observer.rb under the model directory. I have install the 'rails-observers' gem, what am i missing??

I also try this for a random model (user) and it worked fine.
If someone have any other idea of how doing this please tell me. :)